# What is the equivalent object of Exchange (Camel) in Spring Boot?

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel

I am trying to migrate an application built with Camel in Spring Boot, but i'm not using the Exchange object of Camel, so i have to use some other object to do the work of Exchange. Can anybody give me an idea about that?

Comment: So you don't want to use camel at all ? you could use [spring integration](https://spring.io/projects/spring-integration)

Comment: yes, for some reason can't use camel

Answer (score 0):

SpringBoot is not an integration framework like Camel. **[Spring Integration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/) is the counterpart of Camel in the Spring ecosystem**. Although SpringBoot and the Spring framework works very well with Camel too.

However, the [Camel Exchange](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/core/camel-api/src/main/java/org/apache/camel/Exchange.java) is a Camel concept. I think there is **nothing similar in Spring Integration**.

The Camel Exchange is like an internal, enriched message. A wrapper around an in- and out-message (out is deprecated since Camel 3) and it holds additional state information such as Exchange properties (non-routable headers), Exceptions etc.

As far as I know, in Spring integration there is [just the message](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/overview.html#overview-components-message). No wrapper around it.